# Load image src through Ajax by ID?

Tags: ajax

I've been trying to optimize a site and on a warpath at decreasing db queries. One thing I am noticing that's very expensive is `wp_get_attachment_image_src`. On an overview page listing the entire contents of a section, my pages have an image id set in a custom field. If on that page I call `wp_get_attachment_image_src` it requires an additional DB query for each one.

Brainstorming the idea of just outputing the ID in HTML, render the page, and have JavaScript do an Ajax request to the server to do this additional query and get the src.

How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off preloading *all* the images for the current page ahead of actually outputting them. Then you reduce the queries from `n*2` (there are actually two database queries per get image call, one from the `wp_posts` table, the other from `wp_postmeta`) down to just two.

```
$images = [];
foreach ( $pages as $page )
    $images[] = ( int ) get_post_meta( $page->ID, 'image_field', true );

if ( $images = array_filter( $images ) ) {
    new WP_Query([
        'post__in'       => $images,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'post_status'    => [ 'publish', 'inherit' ],
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    ]);
}
```

This is just for demonstrative purposes, but the idea is you build an array of just image ID's, then use a query to pull them all into memory at once. Subsequent image function calls for said IDs will hit the cache rather than the database.